# Vim negative lookahead and negative look behind in one regular expression

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to convert this regular expressions from sublime text into one I can use in vim:
    `(?<![>\w\d])(42|45|21)\s(?!days)`

I would like to match 42, 45, and 21 where they are not immediately proceeded by a <, a word character, or a digit and are not followed by the word days.

In example, I want to find the 42 in this:
   `This is a reference to chapter 42 in the book.`

But not this:
    `This is a reference to chapter <a href="#">42</a>.`

Or this:
    `This is a reference to chapter <a href="#">42 section 35</a>.`

Or this:
    `This book took 42 days to write.`

I am fairly new to regular expressions in general and super new to vim, so please forgive me if this is a malformed regex to begin with.

Comment: You have an extra `)` at the end - is that the problem, or just copy/paste error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it

```
\([>]\)\@<!\<\(4[25]\|21\)\( days\)\@!
```

or

```
\v([>])@<!<(4[25]|21)( days)@!
```

As you can see, syntax for lookaround is different in vim and you have more than one mode for searching with regular expressions I generally use [`nomagic`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27nomagic%27) and `very magic`

Take some time to see the help of magic modes: [`:help /magic`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic)

**EDIT**

Now it includes 45 and 21 too

Comment: Here's a breakdown for people who had a hard time: `\v` means `very magic` and make vim regexes like most other software. `(pattern)@<!` is the negative lookbehind, and `(pattern)@!` is the negative lookahead.